# How to have the button span the whole width?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify card with a layout and rendering some `dynamic vuetify components` inside of the card on checkbox selection which renders either a `divider`, a `spacer`, `toolbar` or `button` but i am not able to figure out how can i make the buttons span the entire width?

Basically the `dynamic button` should look like the button at the end rendering the entire width.

Please check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/ZEbjMPQ?editors=1010).

Please check this working example:-

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      pricing: [{
          text: "Actual price:",
          value: "$17,000",
        },
        {
          text: " Discount",
          value: "$12,345",
        }
      ],
      elements: [{
          title: "Divider",
          value: "v-divider"
        },
        {
          title: "Toolbar",
          value: "v-toolbar"
        },
        {
          title: "Button",
          value: "v-btn"
        }
      ],
      selected: []
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons'>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout row>
        <v-flex xs6>
          <v-card>
            <v-card-text>
              <v-layout row justify-space-between v-for="option in pricing" :key="option.value" class="my-3">
                <span :class="option.class">{{option.text}}</span>
                <component v-for="(el, i) in selected" :key="i" :is="el.value"></component>
                <span>{{option.value}}</span>
              </v-layout>
              <v-layout row justify-center>
                <v-flex xs11>
                  <v-btn block>
                    Request
                  </v-btn>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
          <v-flex v-for="el in elements" :key="el.value">
            <v-checkbox :value="el" v-model="selected" :label="el.title">
            </v-checkbox>
          </v-flex>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: "the whole width?" you talk about the edges of the card? ("no padding").

Comment: my bad, definitely padding. like as much width as a `flex xs11` would take.

Comment: Use `.flex.xs12` (12 = flex-basis: 100%;).

Comment: nevermind. @EzraSiton it worked.

Comment: You can add this as an answer. i'll accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use .flex.xs12 (12 = flex-basis: 100%;)
-or-
remove `xs12` (And add button `block` attribute = `flex: 1 0 auto;`).

```
<!-- block buttons extend the full available width -->
<template>
  <v-btn block>
    Block Button
  </v-btn>
</template>
```

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/buttons/#block